# How to identify unique ID's that have only 1 true condition?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Simple question: How to identify unique ID's that have only 1 true condition?

```
Index ID value condition
0     1   1     False
1     1   3     True
2     1   2     False
3     1   1     False
4     2   3     True
5     2   4     True
6     2   5     True
```

In the case above, ID 1(1 true) would only be identified while ID 2(3 trues) would not.

How would I go about editing the code below? I need to keep the original index and ID in a segmented data frame.

```
df[df['condition']==True]['ID'].unique()
```

Expected output:

```
Index ID value condition
1     1   3     True
```

All the best,

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter`

```
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x : sum(x['condition'])==1)
Out[685]: 
   Index  ID  value  condition
0      0   1      1      False
1      1   1      3       True
2      2   1      2      False
3      3   1      1      False
```